# The CAS management webapp not start

Tags: json, properties, cas

Tomcat does not want to start case-management 6.0.1.
I do not understand I put the json file.
I am not in https.

What do I need to check ?

In cas-management.properties

```
cas.server.name=http://192.168.0.112:8443
cas.server.prefix=${cas.server.name}/cas

mgmt.serverName=http://192.168.0.112:8443

mgmt.serverName=http://192.168.0.112

server.context-path=/cas-management
server.port=8443

mgmt.adminRoles[0]=ROLE_ADMIN
logging.config=file:/etc/cas/config/log4j2-management.xml

cas.serviceRegistry.json.location=file:/etc/cas/services

cas.authn.attributeRepository.stub.attributes.cn=cn
cas.authn.attributeRepository.stub.attributes.displayName=displayName
cas.authn.attributeRepository.stub.attributes.givenName=givenName
cas.authn.attributeRepository.stub.attributes.mail=mail
cas.authn.attributeRepository.stub.attributes.sn=sn
cas.authn.attributeRepository.stub.attributes.uid=uid
```

In the file /etc/cas/services/http_cas_management-1560930209.json

GNU nano 2.7.4

```
Fichier : /etc/cas/services/http_cas_management-1560930209.json
```

```
        {
      "@class" :            "org.apereo.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
      "serviceId" :         "^http://192.168.0.112/cas-management/.*",
      "name" :              "CAS Services Management",
      "id" :                1560930209,
      "description" : "CAS services management webapp",
      "evaluationOrder" : 5500
      "allowedAttributes":["cn","mail"]
    }
```

Thank
Best regard

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Hello,

Here is my cas-management log file:

```

2019-06-24 08:36:15,678 WARN [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext] - Exception encountered during context initialization 

```

Comment: next

- cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'compositeDiscoveryClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/client/discovery/composite/CompositeDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'compositeDiscoveryClient' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.simple.SimpleDiscoveryClientAutoConfiguration':

Comment: Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor tried to access protected method org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor.<init>(Lorg/springframework/core/ResolvableType;Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)

Comment: V (org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor and org.springframework.core.convert.TypeDescriptor are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @6853076b)
2019-06-24 08:36:15,684 WARN [org.springframework.boot.context.properties.migrator.PropertiesMigrationListener] - 
The use of configuration keys that have been renamed was found in the environment:

Comment: Property source 'bootstrapProperties':
 Key: server.context-path
  Replacement: server.servlet.context-path


Each configuration key has been temporarily mapped to its replacement for your convenience. To silence this warning, please update your configuration to use the new keys.

Comment: I don't understand why the service not start.

Comment: Man just edit your post and add the logs. Comments are not for that.